# Exportar dados de php para xls a partir de um link

Tags: php, jquery, microsoft-excel

Estou fazendo um link, que quando o usuário clicar nele deve gerar um arquivo xls. O link tem os data-atributos e deve passar esses atributos para a pagina.php e gerar o xls. Tentei fazer com jquery e não esta dando certo, será que tem alguma outra forma?

```
<a href="#" id="xls" data-unidade="203" data-tema="1">
    Gerar XLS
</a>
```

O jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#xls').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'produto/exportXls',
            data: {
                'tema_id' : $(this).data('tema'),
                'unidade_id' : $(this).data('unidade')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

O php que cria a tabela para gerar o xls

```
$html = '<table><tr>';
$html .= '<td colspan="3">Planilha teste</tr>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td><b>Coluna 1</b></td><td><b>Coluna 2</b></td><td><b>Coluna 3</b></td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>L1C1</td><td>L1C2</td><td>L1C3</td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>L2C1</td><td>L2C2</td><td>L2C3</td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>L3C1</td><td>L3C2</td><td>L3C3</td></tr>';
$html .= '</table>';

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=arquivo.xls" );
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
// Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
echo $html;
```

Só que não esta rolando...

Comment: O html é exibido na tela esse é o problema?

Comment: na verdade não exibe na tela, somente no firebub->Network->preview. E quando eu roda a url direto ele gera o arquivo xls.

Comment: Qual o erro? O que era para acontecer?

Comment: *"Só que não esta rolando..."* é muito vago. Primeiro isole o problema: A aplicação funciona sem AJAX? Se funciona, o problema é no JAvaScript. Se não funciona, é no PHP. Segundo, no seu AJAX, cadê o *callback* de sucesso? Sem ele você não tem como fazer algo com a resposta do servidor. Terceiro: Você precisa mesmo de AJAX para isso? Porque não passar os argumentos via querystring num link uma vez que será feito um download do arquivo?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge era para fazer o download do arquivo.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto ótimas questões que vc levantou... vou testar aqui e aviso. Eu estava imaginando que ao fazer o click no link irá redirecionar para a página do link. Mas irei fazer o teste.

Answer (score 4):

Numa tradução livre das palavras de John Culviner, criador do plugin  [jQuery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/):

> JavaScript, por design, não tem a habilidade de executar tarefas de baixo nível no computador de seus usuários por questões de segurança. Inicializar um diálogo de download é uma dessas limitações.

Sendo assim, de todo jeito, você vai ter que gerar o arquivo no seu servidor e ter um URI válido que aponte para ele. Com PHP você pode fazer algo simples como por exemplo usando [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents)

Feito isso, uma solução grosseira seria no *callback* de sucesso redirecionar manualmente o browser para o URI desse recurso:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/server/action',
    data: {
        'tema_id': $(this).data('tema'),
        'unidade_id': $(this).data('unidade')
    },
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href='arquivo.xls';
    }
});
```

Mas isso não é lá muito apelativo para os padrões da Web moderna. Com o plugin acima, não apenas você componentiza uma solução específica como te oferece uma forma mais elegante de tratamento de erros.

Quando o servidor responde solicitando que a resposta seja tratada como um download, se houver sucesso, o browser não altera a página que o usuário está e mostra a caixa de diálogo apropriada.

Mas quando há um erro (arquivo não existe, por exemplo), o browser é redirecionado para a página padrão de 404 que pode até estar escrita em coreano o que é frustrante pro usuário.

Comment: Uma forma que eu tinha conseguido agora foi usando essa ideia aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/23504028/2161286 que deu certo, mas dai o que fiz mesmo foi fazer o link da sua forma mais simples, sem js nenhum fazendo qualquer tipo de manipulação que dai também deu certo e que é da forma mais correta, assim imagino pelo sei e até mesmo pela sua resposta. Valew

Comment: De todo o jeito o arquivo físico é criado no servidor, inclusive com o próprio file_put_contents() (é mais lento, mas é mais prático). Esse é um ótimo exemplo de que AJAX não é a cura pro câncer. Tem coisas que simplesmente não dá pra fazer ou até dá, mas você tem que dar uma volta enorme quando pode resolver com HTML básico.

Answer (score 1):

1) Altere a chamada ao PHP para um link tradicional e não AJAX;

2) adicione o header seguinte para forçar o download:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
```

Comment: A não ser que esse *header* seja necessário por algum navegador teimoso, ele é desnecessário pois o **Content-disposition** já lidaria coma definição de forçar o download.